# Rewriting statements in full detail with logical operators, but without quantifiers

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I've been given the following question:

Let P and Q be predicates on the set S, where S has two elements, say S={a, b}. Then the statement $\forall xP(x)$ can also be written in full detail as $P(a) \wedge P(b)$. Rewrite the statements below in a similar fashion, using P, Q and logical operators.

I'm having trouble with these 2:
$$\forall x\exists y(P(x) \vee Q(y))$$ 
and
$$\exists xP(x) \wedge \exists yQ(y)$$

For the first one I have: $$\equiv (P(a) \wedge (Q(a) \vee Q(b)) \wedge (P(b) \wedge (Q(a) \vee Q(b))$$

And the second one I have simply: 
$$\equiv (P(a) \vee P(b))\wedge   (Q(a) \vee Q(b)$$

Haven't done anything like this before so any insight is appreciated!

Comment: Why in the 1st one did the $\vee$ connecting $P$ and $Q$ become a $\wedge$? Also, in the 2nd one, did you mean to write $Q(y)$ instead of $P(y)$?

Comment: For the first one, my logic was that for all x, there exists one y (either Q(a) or Q(b)). Not sure if this is rly how to think about this problem. And for the second - yes I just changed it.

Comment: To solve these problems systematically, deal with one quantifier at a time.  Your first formula, when eliminating the first (outermost) quantifier, becomes $\exists y(P(a) \vee Q(y)) \wedge \exists y(P(b) \vee Q(y))$.

Comment: Thank you :) so would it be $(P(a) \vee (Q(a) \vee Q(b)) \wedge (P(b) \vee (Q(a) \vee Q(b)))  $?